# Install and run @cucumber/cucumber in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

We want to use Cucumber in our Node.JS project. It's probably a pretty basic question but I'm following the Cucumber tutorial and I'm getting stuck at the part where you have to run Cucumber in order to test if everything works. How do I run the new Cucumber (@cucumber/cucumber) package? I think that my issue is related to the package change, which is now /@cucumber/cucumber instead of just cucumber. The command ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -f node_modules/cucumber-pretty doesn't work. Furtermore, what does -f means?

Comment: Add a script in your package.json `"test": "cucumber-js"` and run `npm test`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you perhaps also know what the '-f' means?

Comment: It's shorthand for [`--format`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#formats)